# Is it common for border guards to disregard available passport space like in this image?

Tags: passports, passport-stamps

These are stamps from Guadeloupe and Martinique in my mother's passport.

On the left page it's obvious the border guards could've used the right edge. Is it common for them not to?

[image]

Comment: many border guards prefer to be the first stamp on a blank page. Take a look at the related questions over on the right side from people who worry this habit will cause them to run out of blank pages.

Comment: When you stamp probably hundreds of passports per day, do you think you're going to want to mess around lining up the stamp to fit within the freely available space on an already quite full page? Or would you rather just stamp where there's a lot of available space?

Comment: Can only speak for myself, but if I was a passport controllant, I'd instinctively try using up obvious space. If I had been the one to give the second stamp, I would have placed it horizontally (similarly to the last one) next to the first. It's VERY obvious it would fit.

Oh well, just wondered how common it actually is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have to stamp hundreds of passports every day, and I have seen them tending to use a new blank page if available.

You can still ask them politely and nicely to put the stamp in a specific page though!

What I usually do it nicely ask them to place the stamp in a specific page and quickly mention them that I'm trying to save up some page space. Here is from a page that I usually ask Sri Lankan officers to put the stamp in. I'm feeling I could squeeze one or two more here!

[image]

It is mostly the page they find easier to put the seal in. If you have several pages and it is more work for them to find an empty page, they are likely to find the page number you said and just put the stamp there and move on.

Answer (score 4):

A standard passport has about 30 visa pages (varies slightly from country to country). Most passport have a 10 year validity. That means 3 visa pages per year.

For the average (leisure) traveller, which probably travels at most once a year to a country that will put a stamp (or often two) in their passport, that means there's really no need to conserve space at all, and immigration officers, stamping hundreds of passports every day, will certainly not waste even a second to save space, they'll just find the first page they can whack a stamp on in the shortest time possible. That's just human nature.

Business travellers may have more trouble with this, though I expect immigration officers to become a bit more attentive to space requirements once the visa pages start to fill up. Note also that in many countries, you can get passports with more pages, and of course you can renew your passport once it's full or close to. Some will probably have more trouble with actual visas (which take a whole page) rather than stamps.